# Conditional rewrite rule in htacces but only sometimes

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have several valid URL's on my domain which might be access like this:

- mysite.com/somepage
- www.mysite.com/someotherpage
- mysite.com/thirdpage/other
- etc

And some URL's I want to rewrite like this:

- mysite.com/specialpage (to mysite.com/?specialpage)
- www.mysite.com/veryspecialpage (to mysite.com/?veryspacialpage)

I assume that I would have to match the special pages exacly (one rule for each), but www. prefix is optional, how would I do this?

```
RewriteRule ^(www.)?/mysite.com/specialpage mysite.com/?specialpage [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(www.)?/mysite.com/veryspecialpage mysite.com/?veryspecialpage [L,NC,QSA]
```

But can't make that work

Comment: For specific pages use: `RewriteRule ^(page1|page2|page3)/?$ /?$1 [L,QSA,NC]`

Answer (score 1):

The rewrite rule regex doesn't match against the hostname so you can just leave it out:

```
RewriteRule ^specialpage$ /?specialpage [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^veryspecialpage$ /?veryspecialpage [L,QSA]
```